# addressbook example of protocol buffer is not compiling

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

i am trying to compile addressbook example of protocol buffers but it is throwing a error:

> write.cpp(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream': No such file or directory

In write.cpp it encounters `#include <iostream>` and is throwing this error though when i am right clicking on `<iostream>` and clicking on open document it is opening the iostream file.

I have included the path in include directories then also it is showing me the same errors.

I am using Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Your environment might not be set up for C++ or could be broken.

There's an easy way to try to fix it:
Tools -> Import and Export settings -> reset all

I only have VS 2012 installed but I think it should be quite the same in your older version.

Comment: I am running it on Wince platform

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the above issue by putting " " around the search path as it contained spaces between the file names.

and now i am trying to port my Protobuf2.5.0 code to wince for MIPS platform and when i am trying to build it is throwing me the following errors:

1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\ce\include\crtdefs.h(100) : fatal error C1189: #error :  ERROR: Use of C runtime library internal header file.
1>zero_copy_stream_impl.cc
1>..\src\google\protobuf\io\zero_copy_stream_impl.cc(50) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
1>zero_copy_stream.cc

Comment: can anyone tell me what is the Predefined macro for MIPS as in protobuf platform_macro.h __MIPSEL__ is used but in MSDN there is no such predefined macro and the Predefined macro that they mention i.e _M_MRX000 is no longer supported......plz help